# Powershell for JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I made this script in powershell to collect some information from the computer and I need to export to JSON format with some specifications

```
$osinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction STOP | 
            Select-Object @{Name='computername';Expression={$_.CSName}};

Write-Host "Computer_INfo:" 
$osinfo | ConvertTo-Json  

$rede = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ErrorAction STOP | where-object -FilterScript {$_.IPEnabled -eq $true} | Select-Object @{Name='Description';Expression={$_.Description}},
          @{Name='IP_Address';Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}};

Write-Host "LAN_INfo:"
$rede | ConvertTo-Json
```

The result of this command generates this JSON

```
Computer_INfo:
{
"computername":  "DESKTOP-PCJTTEG"
}
LAN_INfo:
[
{
    "Description":  "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter",
    "IP_Address":  "192.168.65.241"
},
{
    "Description":  "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2",
    "IP_Address":  "192.168.10.104"
}
]
```

I wanted it to be this way.

```
{Computer_Info:
[
{
"computername":  "DESKTOP-PCJTTEG"
}
]
},LAN_INfo:{
[
{
    "Description":  "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter",
    "IP_Address":  "192.168.65.241"
},
{
    "Description":  "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2",
    "IP_Address":  "192.168.10.104" }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the structure for your Json by designing your PSCustomObject in the way you desire. To have arrays, even if you have 1 element, add the `@()` array constructor. When converted to json, il will transpose to your missing `[]`

Default depth when converting to Json is 4, which can be adjusted up to 100 layers.
In the case of your output, I adjusted it to avoid missing some content in the final output.

Here's your code, with the rendered output you were looking for.

```
$osinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction STOP | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'computername'; Expression = { $_.CSName } };

$rede = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ErrorAction STOP | where-object -FilterScript { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'Description'; Expression = { $_.Description } },
@{Name = 'IP_Address'; Expression = { $_.IPAddress[0] } };

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Computer_Info = @(
        $osinfo,
        @{'LAN_INfo' = $rede }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```